# Spring security: issue with accessing Authentication object from a child thread after user re-login

Tags: spring-security

A faced with the next issue: I need to get currently logged in user name from a child thread, and for this purpose I use `MODE_INHERITABLETHREADLOCAL` strategy of SecurityContextHolder. All works fine until user log off and log in again. After that `MODE_INHERITABLETHREADLOCAL` do not work. I don't know why and try to find solution. The thing is that after re-login `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()`, invoked from child thread, returns `null` (`SecurityContextHolder.getContextHolderStrategy()` returns `MODE_INHERITABLETHREADLOCAL`).
I set context holder strategy in my security-config.xml

`<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
        <property name="targetClass"  value="org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder"/>
        <property name="targetMethod" value="setStrategyName"/>
        <property name="arguments"><list><value>MODE_INHERITABLETHREADLOCAL</value></list></property>
    </bean>`

I would be grateful if somebody could help me. Thank you in advance!